# Invalid java syntax using ternary operator

Tags: java, ternary-operator

I am implementing a stack using queues. My pop() function originally looked like:

```
public void pop(){
    queue1.isEmpty() ? queue2.poll() : queue1.poll();
}
```

This did not compile. What is wrong with this definition?

Comment: Does your queue1.isEmpty method return a Boolean?

Comment: Does `queue2.poll()` and `queue1.poll()` return the _same_ type?

Comment: What Throwable (Exception or Error) did compilation produce?  In case you are implementing an ArrayDeque it has a pop method that would need overriding -- and it is a natural fit for stack implementation.

Comment: Although this use of the ternary operator is illegal in Java, interestingly it is legal in C/C++. (Not to say that it's good or bad.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign (or return) the `Object` you're polling. Something like

```
public void pop(){
    Object obj = queue1.isEmpty() ? queue2.poll() : queue1.poll();
}
```

or (what I think you really want) - something like

```
public Object pop(){
    return queue1.isEmpty() ? queue2.poll() : queue1.poll();
}
```

See also [JLS-15.25. Conditional Operator `? :`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25).

Answer (score 1):

The conditional operator only works in an *expression* context. A statement is not an expression. In your case you need to use an `if` statement:

```
public void pop(){
    if (queue1.isEmpty()) {
        queue2.poll();
    } else {
        queue1.poll();
    }
}
```

If you are concerned about performance, then don't be. There is absolutely no performance penalty for using an `if` statement.